# Angular 9 - Error de DatePipe

Tags: angular, date, pipe

Estoy trayendo registros de una BBDD.
el json que recibo tiene la fecha correcta:

```
update: "2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Entonces lo quiero mostrar en el frontend formateado con pipe

```
registro.update | date: 'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Y el frontend me muestra

```
sábado, 18/07/2020
```

Es decir, me muestra un dia menos que lo que me muestra lel json.

Les agradeceria si me pueden orientar con este problema.

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento que ves no es un problema del `pipe`, es un problema del `timeZone` de la fecha. DatePipe usa la configuración regional para mostrar la fecha en la zona horaria del usuario.

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

**Método 1:**

template:

```
{{ getFormattedDate(registro.update) | date: 'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

componente:

```
getFormattedDate(date) {
   return date.toISOString().substring(0, date.toISOString().length - 1);
}
```

**Método 2:**

Saca el año, día y mes de tu fecha y luego, construye una fecha nueva con estos valores.

template:

```
{{ getFormattedDate(registro.update) | date: 'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

componente:

```
getFormattedDate(date) {
   let dd = (new Date(data.birthDate)).getUTCDate().toString();
   let mm = ((new Date(data.birthDate)).getMonth()).toString();
   let yy = (new Date(data.birthDate)).getFullYear().toString();
   return new Date(Number(yy), Number(mm), Number(dd));
}
```

**Método 3:**

Si sabes que la fecha se establece como un valor UTC ("+00: 00" o "Z" para la zona horaria), puedes agregar el especificador de zona horaria al DatePipe:

```
{{ getFormattedDate(registro.update) | date: 'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy': 'UTC' }}
```

--

También, si todas tus fechan vienen y/o presentan el mismo problema, puedes crear un `pipe` personalizado que aplique cualquier método de los mencionados y luego, solo debes poner en el template:

```
{{ registro.update | myCustomDatePipe }}
```